# Test whether an id is in a table or a list in jQuery

Tags: jquery, list

I know normally you would have to probably post some code to show working out and stuff, but this is a question I can't really show code for.

I am writing a jQuery plugin, and I wish to test if a received id is in a table or a list.

What I am doing at the moment is is setting a variable called type and sending it into my plugin

Like this:

```
"#tablename".mr_slider({type:"list",effect:"delete"});
```

What I wish to do is to remove the type: variable and let my plugin work out whether it is using a table or a list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can determine the type of an element using the `is()` method. Try this:

```
if ($('#myElement').is('table')) {
    console.log('I am a table!');
}
```

If you want to check if the element is within a table you can use `closest()`:

```
if ($('#myElement').closest('table').length) {
    console.log('I am inside a table!');
}
```

Comment: I think OP doesn’t want to check the element itself, but rather if it is _nested_ into a list or a table – so it would require to go up the DOM tree to check the ancestors, and see what comes first, a list or a table element.

Comment: In either case the `is()` method would work - you just need to traverse the DOM to find the relevant element to test. I updated my answer to check without DOM traversal though.

Comment: I don’t think `closest` is the best choice here – at least if document structures such as having a list inside a table are possible. I’d probably go with `.parents('ul, table')`, and then see which element type the first match (if any) has.

Comment: Without seeing the actual HTML structure it's all guess work unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, of course. But I think we gave the OP enough options to make something out of it now :-)

Comment: `.closest()` is depreciated and no more available in jquery 1.7 above

Comment: @A.K that's not true at all. Only the `.closest( selectors [, context ] )` signature is deprecated. See the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
if ($('#elementID').closest("table").length!=0) {
   console.log("I am in a table").
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan. You have half answered my question. Your first answer works, so I know how to check for a table, but what about list. I have tried if ($('#myElement').is('list')) but that does not seem to work.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams what exactly do you mean by list, is it a `ul`, `li`, `select` or `ol`?

Comment: hello void thanks you give me the clue that solved it. Instead of putting $('#myElement').is('list') I put $('#myElement').is('ul') and now I can identify a list and a table. Thank you all for the help. However I believe it was Rory McCrossan that gave me the best answer. I am not sure how to close this question now because I am new here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my question

```
if ($('#myElement').is('table')) {
    console.log('I am a table!');
}
```

is for checking for a table, and

```
if ($('#myElement').is('ul')) {
    console.log('I am an unordered list!');
}
```

For checking for an unordered list

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.parents()` like this when your id is with in a table or List:

```
checkElement("t2");

function checkElement(id) {
      var elems = $("#" + id).parents();
      for(i=0; i<=elems.length;i++){      
        if($(elems[i]).is('table')) {
            console.log("Table Found");
            alert("Table Found");
        } else if($(elems[i]).is('ul')) {
            console.log("UL Found");
            alert("UL Found");
        } else {
        console.log("Other Element Found");
      }
   } 
}
```

See a [**Demo**](http://codepen.io/ahsanrathore/pen/PZmWRa) by passing different id in `checkElement("t2")` ;